# 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to change the code and put defer but it gives me an error

discord.ext.commands.errors.HybridCommandError: Hybrid command raised an error: Command 'randomfact' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'
Please help me fix

```
class Fun(commands.Cog, name="fun"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.hybrid_command(
        name="randomfact",
        description="Get a random fact."
    )
    @checks.not_blacklisted()
    async def randomfact(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        """
        Get a random fact.
        
        :param context: The hybrid command context.
        """
        # This will prevent your bot from stopping everything when doing a web request - see: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-make-a-web-request
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en") as request:
                if request.status == 200:
                    data = await request.json()
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        description=data["text"],
                        color=0xD75BF4
                    )
                else:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title="Error!",
                        description="There is something wrong with the API, please try again later",
                        color=0xE02B2B
                    )
                await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral = True)   
                await asyncio.sleep(4) 
                await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, ephemeral = True)
```

Comment: Bonjour Hello. Oups. Hello Bonjour ! since the interpreter considers your interaction as a context, maybe try `await interaction.interaction.response.defer(ephemeral = True)`. If this works, it means that instead of an interaction, your bot receive a Context, that hasn't a "response" but an "interaction" attribute.

Comment: (Tu m'en vois ravi :) ). Maybe consider to change your function signature into `async def randomfact(self, context) -> None:` and use then `await context.interaction.response.defer(ephemeral= True)` and `await context.interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, ephemeral = True)` , so it will be easier to read it later, if you have to edit your code in a few months.